# Format Google Sheet to show only go first instance of each value in column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Can Google sheets format a column using QUERY where it only shows the first instance of each unique value in a column.

For example, I have a column of dates ordered descending. I'd like to have a column for year, where at the beginning of each year in the date column, the year is shown on the year column, but just for the first record. 
Like a pivot table, but no expanding and collapsing

I can get a year column to show the year on each row, but not just the first (max) date row for each year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B2:B<>"")*(COUNTIFS(YEAR(B2:B), 
 YEAR(B2:B), ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))=1), YEAR(B2:B), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I think this will work.  How do I add this to a QUERY statement, which has 4 columns: ID, Date, Name, Desc.  =QUERY(importRange("SheetID", "Sheet1!A:D"), "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 Order by Col2 asc",2).  The year would be the new Col1 and everything would be pushed to the right 1 column

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?

Comment: Here is the link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CMPJ1HDi4HQwbOZo7qFAVPsaRhTtbbZ7CzPYk97oETA/edit?usp=sharing.  the data tab would normally be a different google sheet. on the output tab, I would want to get columns B-E from a QUERY and would also liek the query to populate column A, which is the season(year) column.  I would want to enter the QUERY statement in A1 to get columns A-E in the Output tab

Comment: is there any way to create the output the way New tab shows it?https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CMPJ1HDi4HQwbOZo7qFAVPsaRhTtbbZ7CzPYk97oETA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see A1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WNU08I4lctI2YGgrvnQ9-RzxVo0exw68Y78QCPITpo/edit#gid=104531811

Answer (score 0):

Here any else of formula:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA 
  ( 
    { 
      if ( 
         TRANSPOSE ( 
            split ( join ("",left("1," & unique(year(A2:A10)),2) &                             
                rept("0,",countif(year(A2:A10),unique(year(A2:A10)))-1)),",",true,true)
         ) = 1, year(A2:A10),""
      )
      , A2:C10
    }
  )
```

[image]